# When are method attributes evaluated?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, clr

```
[CustomMethodAttribute]
public void MyMethod(string[] args)
{
    // Some implementation
}
```

When will `CustomMethodAttribute` be evaluated and can you do anything to change when this evaluation takes place? Also, care to explain exactly how the compiler manages this trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When will CustomMethodAttribute be evaluated and can you do anything to change when this evaluation takes place?

In general, there is no evaluation that takes place.  A custom attribute is added to the method as *metadata*, and available to be inspected via reflection at runtime as needed.

For details, see [Attributes on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx).

Comment: So, how does one go about using attributes to accomplish something similar to the PrincipalPermissionAttribute?

Comment: @elucid8 In that case, the `PrinciplePermission` class checks, at runtime, the metadata (that attribute).  See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermission(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So, how does the `PrinciplePermission` class intercept the method call to prevent access to the method body based on the presence of the `PrinciplePermissionAttribute`? Is that functionality built into the CLR or could I do something similar to this with a custom attribute?

Comment: Generally speaking, attributes are just containers for data. Something else usually detects the presence of the attribute and acts accordingly. In the case of `PrinciplePermission`, it's something in the CLR.